# UIToolBar missing due to iPhone Message Compose Screen within the app

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, message, uitoolbar

Something going wrong badly due to Message Compose Screen.

I am working on a TabBar based application. In some screens I am showing ToolBar instead of tabBar by setting `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` and its working fine everytime. But In 1 screen I am sending SMS by opening Message Compose Screen within the iphone App. So problem occurs if I open Message Compose Screen and i clicked Cancel button of Message Screen.

So, whenever going back to that module where I was showing ToolBar. So on click of button no ToolBar. Totally blank, no toolbar and no tabbar (tabbar is quite obvious i have already set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed).. But why toolbar now showing due to Compose screen ?

There is no link with compose screen to this screen. Far different implementation and different controllers.

I have check by debugging, Toolbar frame is also fine.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed... had problem with adding it to keyframe window

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the MFMessageComposeViewController has got a navigation bar. Your application should be a navigation based application for that. Otherwise your toolbar's frame position will be affected. I had this kind of problem once. So i changed the application into navigation based but hid the navigation controller.
Hope this might help you,
Happy coding!